# node - jade I am not able to send static html to view

Tags: node.js

I am just parsing a raw html file (index.html) using jade and sending to response of all request. in which i using this function:

```
var http = require('http'),
express  = require('express'),
path     = require('path'),
jade = require('jade'),
fs = require('fs'),
app      = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.all('/', function(req, res, next){

var html;

fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    var fn = jade.compile(data);
    html = fn({name:'Oleg'});
    console.log("data", html);
});

res.send(html);

});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
console.log("i am listning to 3000!");
});
```

But I am not getting any result in the page. what is the issue, where i am wrong here any one help me please?

I moved the "send(html)" to readFile block and i am getting is error:

```
                   ^
```

Error: unexpected token "indent"
    at Object.Parser.parseExpr (D:\app\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:237:15)
    at Object.Parser.parse (D:\app\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:130:25)
    at parse (D:\app\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:100:62)
    at Object.exports.compile (D:\app\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:147:9)
    at D:\app\app.js:23:17
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

my javascript is disabled. please don't mistake for un-proper indents.

Comment: If you move `res.send(html);` to the `fs.readFile` block, it will work.

Comment: You're most likely mixing indentation styles in the jade template. Jade lets you use spaces or tabs but you cannon mix the two. Also, if using spaces, ensure that you are using the same number of spaces for all indents.

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to the jade file. Make sure it's properly indented.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be coming from jade module.  You might want to check the view template.  In addition, res.send(html) must be inside fs.readFile()'s callback:

```
fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
   if(err) throw err;
   var fn = jade.compile(data);
   html = fn({name:'Oleg'});
   console.log("data", html);
   res.send(html);     // <==== move this from outside since
                       // fs.readFile is async.  html might
                       // not have value yet if it's outside
                       // of the callback
});
```